# Variable name in Twig

Tags: html, wordpress, templates, twig

I'm using twig for a couple of pages I designed. A developer is handling the backend, I just need to prepare it as a HTML template, so it could be used in WordPress. When I add a variable to my HTML file, it translates into a field inside the WP page. For example, if there's a title, I add

```
title: 
  type: text
  default: Title goes here
```

And inside the elements:

```
<h1>{{ title | title | raw }}</h1>
```

And it turns into a field user can fill in, that has a default set to the test text. The issue is, the templates are global, as I understand. And if I enter a title default for one var, it ends up being a title default for all of them. I can fix this by naming all the title vars differently, but that results in whatever I put as a var name, it ends up being a field name as well in WP.

I know this is a vague question since I can't show you the files. But is there a way for me to change this? A way I could maybe make the var named title_one display as field name title? I've been going through [twig documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/), but I don't have much knowledge about this and can't figure it out on my own.

Thank you!

Comment: I have a hunch that it's totally not relevant to twig. You didn't mention that's the first code? It's yml i guess. I think you should sort it out with your developer. Maybe you can define separate title types, or title per element type, so more like nested structure?

Comment: Yes, it could be yml. And I would, but I can't reach the dev. So there's no way to add it inside this file, like I did with default text?

Comment: well you can solve it adding different names (title_one, title_two ...) i guess, but without knowing anything else (how it actually works) it's impossible to say anything for sure.

Comment: I see. Well, thank you anyway! :)